# How to integrate a pretrained tensorflow model into a keras layer if the exact input shape is unknown?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing something similar to this tensorflow tutorial: [transfer_learning_audio](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/transfer_learning_audio).

Basically this tutorial uses a pretrained model (YAMNet) in order to extract features (embeddings) and then trains a specific classifier based on those embeddings. The classifier obviously performs a simpler, use-case specific task.

I'm interested in the part of the tutorial where they integrate the YAMNet model and the classifier into a single, keras model:

```
saved_model_path = './dogs_and_cats_yamnet'

input_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='audio')
embedding_extraction_layer = hub.KerasLayer(yamnet_model_handle,
                                            trainable=False, name='yamnet')
_, embeddings_output, _ = embedding_extraction_layer(input_segment)
serving_outputs = my_model(embeddings_output)
serving_outputs = ReduceMeanLayer(axis=0, name='classifier')(serving_outputs)
serving_model = tf.keras.Model(input_segment, serving_outputs)

serving_model.save(saved_model_path, include_optimizer=False)
```

Now, the question I have is: how could I do this for a **somewhat** more complex model? Namely, I'm having issues when trying to integrate the exact same YAMNet model into my own model. This is the architecture of my own model:

```
# Build model using functional API
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 1024), name='inputs')

dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs)
gru_1 = tf.keras.layers.GRU(48, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                            dropout=0.15, recurrent_dropout=0,
                            return_sequences=True, name='gru_1',
                            reset_after=True)(dense_1)
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output_1')(gru_1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense_2)
```

My model receives inputs of shape `(BATCH_SIZE, NUMBER_OF_FRAMES, 1024)`. I suppose the `BATCH_SIZE` axis is obvious enough. The `NUMBER_OF_FRAMES` axis comes from YAMNet, since YAMNet provides a 1024-vector embedding per every frame of audio. An audio frame is each 0.48secs in YAMNet.

I tried to "stack" the models, just as the tutorial shows:

```
my_model = tf.keras.saving.load_model('/load/my/model')

input_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='audio')

embedding_extraction_layer = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/yamnet/1',
                                            trainable=False, name='yamnet')

_, embeddings_output, _ = embedding_extraction_layer(input_segment)

serving_outputs = my_model(embeddings_output)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model" (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "gru_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 32)

Call arguments received by layer "model" (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None
```

I suppose that it's pretty clear where this issue is originating from. I'm using a recurrent neural network and somehow need to specify that YAMNet will be providing me with inputs of shape `(NUMBER_OF_FRAMES, 1024)` but I cannot find a way to actually do that. I couldn't find my answer on [hub - KerasLayer](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/KerasLayer#used-in-the-notebooks).